# Include_partial to string without break lines

Tags: php, string, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I have this code:

```
$var = "<?php include_partial('box-2')?>";
```

that results in:

```
$var = "
<form id='form' method='post' action='/test/search' name='name3636'>
<div id="table" class="table">
....
"
```

But i am getting:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

So, my question is, how can i pass the include partial result to a string without break lines to avoid this error?

Comment: This is due to linebreaks  from php output

Comment: @shadow yes, but i don't know how to avoid the break lines from symfony. this is auto generated

Comment: You should avoid that kind of code

Comment: remove double quotes from "<?php include_partial('box-2')?>"; and check again.

Comment: It is not about line breaks. You have to use only one type of quotes (' or ") or escape them e.g. in `<div id=\"table\" class=\"table\">`;

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

why you don't use `ob_start();`? Its like this

```
ob_start();
include('you_file.php');
$res=ob_get_clean(); // $res is output of your file

$var=$res;
```

or

```
$var=someFunctionToFilter($res);
```

Comment: that doesn't make a difference to specified problem, however i didn't

Comment: i didnt do that, cant u understand and i cant vote, my voting limit has been reached already

Comment: oh sorry I didn't read it carefully sorry man but at least tell me what you think about my answer. ($

Comment: Actually i have not that much idea about your answer

Answer (score 0):

Use get_partial instead:

```
$var = get_partial('box-2');

//Do something with $var
```